# Connecting DellBoomi with BullHorn API

Tags: integration, boomi, ipaas

I want to connect my Dell Boomi application with Bull Horn API. Before that I have to register with Bullhorn and then do OAuth 2 authentication. Can anyone please help me how to register with BullHorn & then how to do OAuth 2 authentication for BullHorn in Dell Boomi?

Comment: Have you visited with Dell Boomi support for that?

Comment: yes i have posted my question in boomi community but its been a couple of days and I haven't got any response.

Comment: It's possible that there aren't as many active users in the community with the kind of problem or solution you are seeking. You may experience the same kind of lack of response here. If I were you, I'd pay Boomi's professional service to help out.